# Filter array, according to the filter of another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, filter

There are two arrays - first one is about dates, and the second one shows spendings, being made that day:

```
var arrayOfDates = [01.07, 01.07, 03.07, 04.07, 05.07, 05.07, 05.07]
var arrayofCosts = [3, 8, 2, 2, 8, 6, 9]
```

I want to filter the `arrayOfDates` for unique elements. And in the second array show the highest-value spending for each day.
So the result should be:

```
var arrayOfDatesModifed = [01.07, 3.07, 04.07, 05.07]
var arrayofNumbersModifed = [8, 2, 2, 9]
```

So this idea consists of 3 phases:

1. Filter `arrayOfDates` for unique elements
2. For each unique date find corresponding item(s) in `arrayofCosts`
3. Find the biggest value in `arrayofCosts` for each date

Though each of this tasks individually may be simple, I cant figure it out how to accomplish them altogether. Your help will be very much appreciated

Comment: First you shouldn't have 2 arrays, but only one. With a custom `struct`, or at minima, a tuple/dict: like `struct MyStruct { let cost: Int, let Date: Date }`. For your issue, you could `zip()` to link them, then remove "duplicates", keeping highest value.

Comment: Larme, thanks for your help! I wrote here a simplified version of a whole task. For other purposes of the project, imo, it is easier to work with arrays . For this specific task I can merge them in dictionary. But if there could be a solution for arrays as they are - it would be great.

Comment: An array of custom Struct (or dict) would be a better approach. And you are exactly in the situation why: You have values that are "linked" with the same index, but if you remove/modify/change position one of them, you need to apply the same calculation on the other array for the same index. So sorting, filtering, became a lot harder to do. it's doable, but a lot of extrawork.  Now, if you have more than 2 arrays (ie one array for each property, you'll see the nightmare).

Comment: Got it, thanks! I'l try to build a dictionary or a struct than.

Comment: Use an array of Structs. That is by far the cleanest solution. If you MUST filter one array using the contents of another array, use zip like in Sh_Khan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with those with comments. Working with individual arrays is going to be a real pain.

Let's implement a struct to hold our data.

```
struct Entry: CustomStringConvertible {
    let date: Double
    let cost: Int

    var description: String {
        "(\(date), \(cost))"
    }
}
```

These are just the entries from your example:

```
let entries: [Entry] = [
    .init(date: 01.07, cost: 3),
    .init(date: 01.07, cost: 8),
    .init(date: 03.07, cost: 2),
    .init(date: 04.07, cost: 2),
    .init(date: 05.07, cost: 8),
    .init(date: 05.07, cost: 6),
    .init(date: 05.07, cost: 9),
]
```

The first thing I would do is group all entries by date:

```
let groupedEntries = Dictionary(grouping: entries) { $0.date }
print(groupedEntries)
```

Which gives us an unordered Dictionary where the key is the date and the value is an array of entries having the same date:

```
[1.07: [(1.07, 3), (1.07, 8)], 5.07: [(5.07, 8), (5.07, 6), (5.07, 9)], 3.07: [(3.07, 2)], 4.07: [(4.07, 2)]]
```

The next thing I would do is extract the entry with the max cost in each group and discard the entries with the lower costs. We don't need those. So now we have an array of entries where the low cost elements have been filtered out.

```
let uniqueDateMaxEntry = groupedEntries.compactMap { _, entries in
    return entries.max(by: { $0.cost < $1.cost })
}
print(uniqueDateMaxEntry)
```

This gives us:

```
[(1.07, 8), (4.07, 2), (5.07, 9), (3.07, 2)]
```

As you can see, the array is not sorted by the date. So we can do that now

```
let sortedUniqueDateMaxEntry = uniqueDateMaxEntry
    .sorted { $0.date < $1.date }
print(sortedUniqueDateMaxEntry)
```

And finally that gives us:

```
[(1.07, 8), (3.07, 2), (4.07, 2), (5.07, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
var arrayOfDates = [01.07, 01.07, 03.07, 04.07, 05.07, 05.07, 05.07]
var arrayofCosts = [3, 8, 2, 2, 8, 6, 9]

var item = 0.0
var arrayOfDatesModified = [Double]()
var arrayOfCostsModified = [Int]()
var maxCosts = 0
var indexFor = 0

//Enumerated function helps to get the element with corresponding index
for (index, element) in arrayOfDates.enumerated() {
    let cost = arrayofCosts[index]
    ///If item is not same as before then its the new item - 01.07(new), 01.07(old), 03.07(new)
    if item != element {
        item = element
        maxCosts = cost
        arrayOfDatesModified.append(item)
        arrayOfCostsModified.insert(maxCosts, at: arrayOfDatesModified.count - 1)
    } else {
        ///If same element cost is higher then replacing with the higher cost
        if maxCosts < cost {
            maxCosts = cost
            arrayOfCostsModified.remove(at: arrayOfDatesModified.count - 1)
            arrayOfCostsModified.insert(maxCosts, at: arrayOfDatesModified.count - 1)
        }
    }
}

print(arrayOfDatesModified)
print(arrayOfCostsModified)
```

The above simple for loop also be the solution but its not optimised one. 
The swift language have many advanced concept in the latest versions, We should avoid the above complex way to solve the problem.

1. Unnecessary variable declarations
2. More time and space complexity
3. Missing the concepts map filter and struct , grouping etc.,

It just an example for: Should not solve the problem for current situation , should consider the future perspective as well.
Its not the solution for you Sergey_VC , just trying to help someone trying quick fix in Online.